# Thinking with Threads in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety

I've got a static class that has a private dictionary object.  This object is initialized in the static constructor, and is then modified every time a TimerElapsed event is raised by a timer object (also located in the static class).

My pages use a get() method to access the dictionary.  These are pages viewable by the public, so many of these may happen at once.

Do I need to worry about locking the dictionary object to prevent a page from trying to read it while it's being updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find that using ConcurrentDictionary (if you are using .NET 4) to be a more reliable solution. Otherwise you may run in to problems when two or more threads attempt to write (or read/write) at the same time.

If you don't have .NET 4, you may prefer to wrap up your dictionary into a class that uses locks to prevent access to the shared bits so you don't have locks scattered everywhere.

Comment: I must not have been clear: there is only ever one thread writing to the dictionary at a time - the one handling the TimerElapsed event; everything else is just a read operation.

Comment: Yes, that's okay. You have 2 or more threads accessing the information: 1 writing and 1 or more reading.

Comment: You can have as many readers as you like and you don't require locks. As soon as you add one writer then you need to take precautions to ensure the safety of the data.

Comment: Alright, thanks. That's what I thought - just wanted to make sure.